# type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget?'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

IM trying to call on Tap method, what I want now is change it to a future method because on Tap the method is not ready because im calling a firebase query . So heres first my method
where the onTap function is

```
child: InkWell(
  onTap: () async {
    setState(() {
      israting = true;
    });
  },
  child: israting
      ? buildBody(videos.data()['likes'], videos.data()['id'])
      : Icon(
          Icons.star,
          size: 37,
          color: videos.data()['likes'].contains(uid)
              ? Colors.yellow
              : Colors.white,
        ),
),
```

So im giving the buildBody 2 parameters from a streambuilder
and then thats the function

```
buildBody(videoid, video) async {
    if (videoid.contains(uid)) {
     await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("videos")
          .doc(video)
          .collection("uservotes")
          .doc(uid)
          .get()
          .then((value) {
        votefromfirebase = value.data()["rating"];
      });
      return Container(
          child: Stack(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(3, 7, 0, 0),
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              child: RatingBarIndicator(
                rating: votefromfirebase,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => InkWell(
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.star,
                    color: Colors.amber,
                  ),
                ),
                itemCount: 5,
                itemSize: 31.0,
                direction: Axis.horizontal,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                print(video);
                letuservoting = true;

                setState(() {
                  _userRating = 0.0;
                  israting = false;
                });

                dislike(idovvideo, _userRating);
              },
              child: Text(
                "Clear",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ));
    } else {
      return Container(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(3, 7, 0, 0),
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: RatingBarIndicator(
                  rating: _userRating,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _userRating = index + 1.toDouble();
                      });

                      likevideo(video, _userRating);
                    },
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.star,
                      color: Colors.amber,
                    ),
                  ),
                  itemCount: 5,
                  itemSize: 31.0,
                  direction: Axis.horizontal,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
              child: TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  letuservoting = true;

                  setState(() {
                    _userRating = 0.0;
                    israting = false;
                  });

                  dislike(idovvideo, _userRating);
                },
                child: Text(
                  "Clear",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  buildprofile(String url) {
    return Container(
      width: 50,
      height: 50,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            left: (50 / 2) - (50 / 2),
            child: Container(
              width: 50,
              height: 50,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
              ),
              child: Container(
                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60),
                  child: Container(
                      height: 110,
                      width: 110,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      child: url != null && url != "profilepictureer"
                          ? Image.network(
                              url,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            )
                          : Image.asset(
                              'assets/profilepictureer.png') // Your widget is here when image is no available.
                      ),
                ),
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    border: new Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 4)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

At the moment im getting this error

```
The following _TypeError was thrown building:
type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget?'

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      _VideopageofcurrentuserState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:wichtigdenyady/taking%20videos/currentuservideos.dart:310:47)
#1      SliverChildBuilderDelegate.build
package:flutter/…/widgets/sliver.dart:455
#2      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement._build
package:flutter/…/widgets/sliver.dart:1201
#3      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.performRebuild.processElement
package:flutter/…/widgets/sliver.dart:1145
#4      Iterable.forEach (dart:core/iterable.dart:257:30)
```

The error throws in the onTap function

Comment: You can't use async method during building, this is causing your error: `israting   ? buildBody(videos.data()['likes'], videos.data()['id']) : Icon`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `buildBody` function cannot be an `async` function.
You should move the call to Firebase out of this function and use the result of it in state, instead.

An async function always returns a `Future`. Because the return type isn't defined, it assumes it will return a `Future<dynamic>`. If you defined the return type as `Widget buildBody(videoid, video) async`, the IDE would show an error.

In your `onTap` function, you can make the call:

```
onTap: () async {
  setState(() {
    israting = true;
  });
  if(!videos.data()['likes'].contains(uid)) return; // don't call firebase if uid is not in videoid
  final value = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("videos")
      .doc(video)
      .collection("uservotes")
      .doc(uid)
      .get();
  setState(() {
    votefromfirebase = value.data()["rating"];
  });
},
```

Next, change the `buildBody` function to a non-async function and check if `votefromfirebase` is in the state

```
Widget buildBody(videoid, video) {
  if (votefromfirebase == null) {
    return Container(); // return empty container, progress indicator, or anything else
  }
  // else return the normal body
  return Container(
    child: Stack(
      // rest of this widget
```

Comment: Yes that solved it I also changed if (votefromfirebase == null) { to  if (!videoid.contains(uid)) { and also do  a If else inside the on tap but it was you idea so thanks men